# Laravel 4 - Eloquent 'where' only if exists

Tags: laravel-4, conditional-statements, eloquent

I'm working in a search engine, and I have something like this in my Controller:

```
$user = User::where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
                            ->where('position', $position)  
                            ->where('age', $age)                            
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DES')
                            ->paginate(10);
```

What I want is to use the `$position` and `$age` filters only if they exist. I mean, if I only set the `keyword`, I expect the application to show me all the users with this keyword (whatever its position and age are).

I know a way to do it... using `if($position == '')... else...`, but I would like to do (if possible) in my Eloquent consult. Something like... `->where('position' ? $position)`.

Any idea how to do it in the simplest way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using if conditions would be the best way to do this. As far as I know the functionality your after isn't built into Eloquent.

I would do it using conditionals like so:

```
$query = User::where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');

if($position) {                            
    $query->where('position', $position);
}

if($age) {                            
    $query->where('age', $age);
}                                                      

$user = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DES')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your controller clean and avoid if - else you can create some scopes in your model.

For exemple :

```
public function scopePosition($query, $position)
{
    //If $position in empty, return the query without where clause
    return !($position == '') ?  $query->where('position', $position) : $query;
}
```

And :

```
public function scopeAge($query, $age)
{
    //If $age in empty, return the query without where clause
    return !($age== '') ?  $query->where('age', $age) : $query;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$user = User::where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->position($position)
        ->age($age)               
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DES')
        ->paginate(10);
```

More abour query scope:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: I've tried it, and I have the next error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::position()`. I'm assuming that I have to create the `scopePosition` in my Position.php (model)...